# How to insert a date inside the filename with logrotate

Tags: linux, logrotate

I need to set logrotate to rotate logs files from an application running on the server.
I need the date inside the filename.

I set dateext and also dateformat to add a - in the date.
The result filename is:whatever.csv_2012-03-03

I would like the timestamp to be part of the filename keeping safe the extension; Whatever_2012-03-03.csv.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To insert the date within the filename (and not as extension) of a file under Linux while rotating a file it is correct to use:

```
# Daily rotation
    daily

# We keep original file live
    copytruncate

# Rotation is 1 so we have always .1 as extension
    rotate 1

# If file is missing keep working
    missingok

    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            day=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
            mv blabla.csv.1 /var/www/gamelogs/dir/blabla$day.csv
    endscript
}
```

This is simple and works fine.

Comment: I like this solution. If I get it right, it has a side effect: logrotate will no longer limit the number of kept files. If intended, that's fine.

Comment: It's easy enough to add a `find $logdir -mtime +$maxage -delete` statement to your postrotate script.

Comment: @Rob, so, what's the point of actually using logrotate, then?

Comment: @cnst Not much, besides putting the log rotation code with other log rotation code, so a future sysadmin can fix it to use the dateext if and when the segfault issue goes away.

Comment: The `rotate 1` is too restrictive.

Comment: If your logs are moving very fast you will lose some data due to the usage of copytruncate. Did some tests using seq and redirecting the output to a logfile and validated this.

Answer (score 73):

You should be able to keep the extension apart, e.g. `whatever.2012-03-03.csv`, with the following configuration:

```
whatever.csv {
  dateext
  dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
  extension .csv
  ...
}
```

Note the `dateext` is deliberately empty.

Comment: I've tried this, but the date is added on each rotation, so I get `file.log`, `file.2014-01-08.log` and `file.2014-01-07.2014-01-08.log` etc.

Comment: I found that the `extension` should have the `.` so the correct form is `extension .csv`. This is also followed in `compressext` as in `compressext .bz2`

Comment: Also, it should be `dateformat .%Y-%m-%d` (the first dot is for the date, the second for the extension). @chrisdew that is probably because you are using a wildcard, so *logrotate* is trying to rotate both `file.log` and `file.2014-01-07.log`. Either use a fixed name, or use the `olddir` option to move rotated files to a different directory so they don't get picked up by the wildcard.

Comment: The dateformat option causes a segfault for me https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/ticket/39

Comment: @Rob sadly fedorahosted is an ex-service: "fedorahosted.org was retired on March 1st, 2017".